# Message is not defined - error.ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If I search for http://localhost:3000/buyersearch/buyersearch I get this error:

[image]

All my other routes work except this one.

The route is getting an error from error.ejs. Why?

**buyerSearch.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/WishList';

//buyerIDSearch
router.get('/buyerSearch', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.query.buyerID;

  if (!id || !parseInt(id)) {
    res.render('error', {
      error: "Please enter an Buyer Identification Number"
    });
  } else {
    mongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        res.render('error', {
          error: "Failed to connect"
        });
      } else {
        var WishListDB = db.collection('orders');
        WishListDB.find({
          "_buyerID": parseInt(id)
        }).toArray(function (err, result) {
          if (err || !result || result.length == 0) {
            res.render('error', {
              error: "No order found with that ID number"
            });
          } else {
            res.render('order', {
              order: result[0]
            })
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js references**

```
var buyerSearch = require('./routes/buyerSearch');
app.use('/buyerSearch', buyerSearch);

**buyerSearch.ejs**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <p>Welcome</p>

  <li><%buyerSearch.buyerID %></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `"Please enter an Buyer Identification Number"` try inserting `new Error("Please enter an Buyer Identification Number")` and similarly on the other errors

Comment: You need to pass the field: message in your render method

Comment: @e-sundin  How? can u show me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your error.html template needs to be called like this:

```
res.render("error", {
   message: "Please enter an Buyer Identification Number",
   error: {status:"", stack:""}
});
```

The status and stack values have to be adjusted. They may come from an Error object.

Answer (score 0):

res.render("error", {
   message: "Please enter an Buyer Identification Number",
   error: {status:"", stack:""}
});